# How do I run python script on BlueStacks android emulator?

Tags: python, scroll, automation, mouse, bluestacks

So there is an app called tandem, and it's on BlueStacks the android emulator, and I need to send automated messages to people I have followed on that app, without me having to scroll through everyone and sending them messages one by one, is there a way for me?

This app is not available on the web, so I have to use bluestacks.

Someone successfully made a spam bot using Python [here](https://codeexperiments.quora.com/Whatsapp-spam-bot-in-python-with-pyautogui), but that was for whatsapp.

[Here's](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/923766579076939797/924313718500782090/Skarmavbild_2021-12-25_kl._15.52.35.png) what I meant by having followed a list of users.

Also, I want to know how I can make it so that, if there is a specific sentence written, that the bot would spam another message instead. Let's say I write ”hello, how are you?” and the bot goes through other messages with the exact same messages, and spam another automated message, like ” I am doing great thanks”?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.